# Login to the SSH server

Tags: windows-7, ssh

I've set up `FreeSSHd` on my `Win7` to use

> NT authentication

. As long as i have a system user password set i can login via `putty`. But now i've removed system password for the user and i can't login via `ssh` anymore.

What i have to do to login if the authentication method is "NT authentication" and the user have now no passwd set?

Comment: Have you logged out of the system and then back onto it with the account with no password and then try again after the password is set to blank or whatever? Simple enough to try just in case it helps you troubleshoot or makes it work as expected. Just throwing out the idea to you.

Comment: If FreeSSHd is adapted or based on OpenSSH (can't really find a lot of info), it may simply not let you log in without a password.  OpenSSH tends to have a lot of failsafes built into it, like not allowing you to use a key if file permissions are not set correctly.